# JavaScript define and return a variable on one line

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, if I want to return a variable but don't want to modify it or leak it into the global scope, can I define and return it on one line like this?

```
return var Foo = 'bar'
```

However, I don't think I've seen this anywhere, I more commonly see this:

```
var Foo = 'bar'
return Foo
```

The first one is a bit less redundant, but is it bad practice?

Comment: Why not simply `return 'bar';` ?

Comment: No, you can't do it like that, as will be indicated by the SyntaxError you'll get.

Comment: The first one isn’t valid JavaScript.

Comment: What would it accomplish? Once the value has been returned, the variable won't exist anyway.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire: Probably for a closure.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire If you were in a object I would. Right?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey what do you mean, "in a object"?

Comment: @Pointy In a JSON object? Right?

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: you can’t return anything from an object, because an object isn’t a function. Could you explain what you mean in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Pointy http://jsfiddle.net/YCnhe/

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: you’ll notice that in your example, nothing is being explicitly returned from the function. So as far as I can see, it’s not what JacksonGariety is asking about.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YCnhe/1/

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey you are not using any scoped variables there....

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey `this.val = e;` is not a variable declaration. A variable declaration statement starts with the keyword `var`.

Comment: Oh sorry... I didn't realize

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: `this.val = e` is a property assignment. The `e` variable is being assigned to the `val` property of the object `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see why you would want to do that since once you `return` you are **out of scope**.

Just do

```
return 'bar';
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, you'll definitely need to *declare* the variable in the scope you want it in.  You can then *set* the value, and return it in one line:

```
var Foo; // Declares Foo in this scope, though this expression has no L-Value
return (Foo = 'bar'); // Sets Foo to 'bar' and returns the value of Foo
```

It's questionable *why* you're doing this though.  Ideally, `Foo` would be declared somewhere else in some parent scope.  Or, you'd return a new function that would *enclose* the value of Foo.

Comment: @dandavis - No technical reason, I just like the look better.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a bit difficult to offer a useful answer without understanding what you’re trying to do, but this:

```
return var Foo = 'bar'
```

isn’t valid JavaScript, so you certainly can’t do it that way.

I agree that your second example is redundant - there’s no point declaring a variable in a function if you’re only going to refer to it when you return it. The way to remove that redundancy is to not declare a variable at all:

```
function exampleFunction() {
    return 'bar';
}
```

Comment: @rae1n: Because Paul says there's no point, but Paul doesn't actually know this.

Comment: @user2736012 Where is the point? I agree, there is no point... Once you return you are out of scope...

Comment: @Neal: If a new closure created in the function needs to make use of the variable, then it needs to be declared.

Comment: @user2736012 ... if you are using `var foo` then returning right away then `foo` will never be in anyone's scope. (Unless `foo` is a function of some sort...)

Comment: @user2736012: sure, but that’s not the case in the OP’s example. If that’s what the OP’s trying to do, that detail should be added to the question.

Comment: @Neal: It will be if a new function was created in the same scope, and retained, e.g. as an event handler.

Comment: @Neal well, it's possible that the function had previously "exported" a local function by stuffing a reference to it into a global variable, but it doesn't make the question make any more sense; what's the motivation for saving a line of code in a function that contains another function declaration?

Comment: @Neal: I’m not sure that’s true. I think because of JavaScript variable hoisting, you could declare a function within a function, then declare and return a variable after it, and the function inside the returned function would still have access to it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite there is no hoisting when you use a `var` declaration.

Comment: @Neal: When you use `var`, it *is* hoisted. Therefore, if the syntax OP wanted was possible, the variable could be declared, initialized, and have its value given to the `return` statement all at the same time, and any handlers created above it would have access to the initialized variable when invoked.

Comment: @Neal: so, what I’m thinking of is this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvg5V/ `foo` gets hoisted so that `innerFunction` knows about it, and by the time `innerFunction` is called, `foo` has a value.

Comment: @user2736012: oh, and when I said “refer to it”, I intended that to include accessing the variable in an inner function.